# Cross referencing dsl elements in xtext from a jar

Tags: xtext, cross-reference

I have a DSL written in xtext. Lets say the extension is dmodel. I have created a project with two files `a.dmodel` and `b.model` based on the DSL and various elements inside them are able to cross reference each other in the editor.

Lets say, I would like to move `a.dmodel` to a jar and add it to a jar (and possibly add the jar to the project) and still be able to cross reference the elements from b.dmodel. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works out of the box. You simply put the jar with the a.dmodel on the classpath of a java projects that contains the b.dmodel. Xtext will pick up that information and make the elements in a.dmodel referable.

Comment: It works as you mentioned. Earlier, I created a pure xtext project(not a java project) and was wondering how to add the jar. Thanks a lot.